# PyQt cannot execute a minizinc process

Tags: pyqt, pyqt6, minizinc

I am trying to run minizinc from a pyqt application. Instead of producing a result it will just return ====ERROR===
What is happening here

I have tried to use pythons minizinc package as well as simply calling the minizinc cli but neither works. For example if I run `subprocess.run(["minizinc", "test.mzn"])` from a separate clean python file I get a correct result, however if I run:

```py
self.p = QProcess()
self.p.start("minizinc", ["test.mzn"])
```

from my PyQt class
I get ====ERROR====

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a bug within pyqt6. After switching my code to PySide everything works perfectly